# Lorentz factor correction for luminosity

Tags: astrophysics, gamma-rays, luminosity

I am looking at the physics behind gamma ray bursts, working through a comprehensive review [Kumar & Zhang (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0679v1) (arXiv link).

On page 92, Eq (111) the luminosity or a relativistically expanding plasma is given as:
$$L =4\pi r^2g(r) \sigma_B T'^4(r) \Gamma^2(r) $$

where $\Gamma$ is the Lorentz factor and $g(r)$ the number of degrees of freedom.

I am familiar with the standard form of the Luminosity 
$$L =4\pi r^2 \sigma_B T'^4(r)$$

Can anyone explain where the Lorentz factor and degrees of freedom corrections come in? I understand that $g(r)$ is related to the particles of the plasma and $\Gamma$ to the relativistic expansion, but am unsure exactly how to bring these in.

Comment: NB: It is typically better to link to the abstract page, rather than the PDF; especially in the case of a ~250 page document.